# How can I run Blocking operations in RestEasy Reactive with Qute?

Tags: quarkus, reactive, blocking, quarkus-qute

In Quarkus documentation they say:

> It is now recommended to use RESTEasy Reactive, which supports both traditional
> blocking workloads and reactive workloads equally well.

Actually I try their sample `hibernate-orm-panache-quickstart` and it works properly calling blocking repository method from a Rest Controller.

But what about Qute?

If my `pom.xml` contains the `quarkus-resteasy-qute` dependency, the build fails with:

```
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.steps.CapabilityAggregationStep#aggregateCapabilities threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please make sure there is only one provider of the following capabilities:
[ERROR] capability io.quarkus.rest is provided by:
[ERROR]   - io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive:3.0.4.Final
[ERROR]   - io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:3.0.4.Final
[ERROR]
```

If my `pom.xml` contains the `quarkus-reasteasy-reactive-qute` dependency, the build is OK, but, if I call a Rest method that executes a repository method and wants to return a `TemplateInstance` object, it fails with:

```
io.quarkus.runtime.BlockingOperationNotAllowedException: You have attempted to perform a blocking operation on a IO thread. This is not allowed, as blocking the IO thread will cause major performance issues with your application. If you want to perform blocking EntityManager operations make sure you are doing it from a worker thread.
```

Comment: Have you tried annotating the endpoint with `@Blocking`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @geoand, I have to annotate with @Blocking the REST method.